# Using a certificate for Azure subscription logs - 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, azure, ssl

Background:

I have a Windows Service which polls Azure subscription logs (API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715318.aspx)

On my local development machine the service is set to log on as my account. The X509 certificate was imported under CurrentUser\Personal and in the source code where I check the cert store I have:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

Issue:

The service works fine on my dev machine, it can retrieve data from the API.
On the testing machine I get this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

The service is set to log on as a specific user, dmz\aaseclg1 and the current user\personal cert store has the required certificate.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: image of password prompt:

[image]

Comment: Was the certificate created on your Dev box? How did you export it from your dev box and install it on your test box?

Comment: What happens if you load the cert from a file instead of from the cert store?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri the cert was created on my dev machine, copied to the server and imported via the certification snap in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error when I export the certificate from the machine on which it is created and while exporting, I choose to import it in `.cer` format (i.e. without exporting private keys). Can you try by exporting the certificate from your dev box in `pfx` format and then copy the file on your test box and import it again in your test box by selecting the file and installing the certificate?

**UPDATE**

I was able to reproduce this. When you import the certificate, please make sure that you have unchecked the checkbox which reads "Enable strong private key protection" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

When I check this checkbox, every time I use this certificate it prompts me to enter a password. Now I was using a GUI application so I could see that box. In your case since you are consuming the certificate through a Windows Service (a non UI thingie), this box never shows and you think the service is hanging.

Comment: I did just that and now the code is hanging. I use Enterprise logging and the logs stopped being generated at some point after the last log and before the next (the code which accesses the store).

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird. Only thing we have changed is how your certificate is created/used so that you don't get 403 error. Does your service hang on your dev box as well? Could you share some code?

Comment: No it does not hang at all. When I imported the cert on the TEST box the import wizard asked me for the password I set (expected) then I had to enter another password to add a protected item. I did not have to do that on my DEV box so maybe security/access rights?

Comment: `... then I had to enter another password to add a protected item` - this step is confusing. Normally the only password you would need to specify is the password for pfx cert which you already did when you're importing the certificate.

Comment: See updated question - that dialog appears after clicking Finish.

Comment: Sorry ... had issues with Internet at work and hence delay in responding. Please see my updated answer. HTH.

Comment: Well I do not know the issue. The "hanging" issue is solved, thanks. I did as you said above and on the test box I still have issues. On my local machine I sometimes get a 403 forbidden and sometimes do not. Both my local machine and the test box are configured to use the same proxy. The only thing that bugs me is how it sometimes works on the local machine, but NEVER works on the test box, making me think it may not be the proxy at fault.